# How to get pod start time in millisecond in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to get the performance of the pod scheduling.

When kubectl describe pod performancetestpod. We will get something similar as shown below

```
Type    Reason     Age   From                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                       -------
  Normal  Scheduled  21s   default-scheduler          Successfully assigned default/performancetestpod to ip-172-31-22-111
  Normal  Pulled     20s   kubelet, ip-172-31-22-111  Container image "centos:7.6.1810" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    20s   kubelet, ip-172-31-22-111  Created container
  Normal  Started    20s   kubelet, ip-172-31-22-111  Started container
  Normal  Killing    10s   kubelet, ip-172-31-22-111  Killing container with id docker://performancetestpod:Need to kill Pod
```

1, Is there any way to get the age in milliseconds.

2, Is there any other way to get values in milliseconds for pod start, for eg: by using prometheus etc

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there is no way to get  milliseconds using kubectl in the way you do it.
Answering your 2nd question - take a closer look at [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics).
As per [A Deep Dive into Kubernetes Metrics](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-6-kube-state-metrics-14f4e7c8710b) article:

**Object Creation Time**

Often is it helpful to know at what time objects in Kubernetes where created. Kube-state-metrics exposes a creation time for almost all the objects it tracks. The metric name follows the pattern `kube_<OBJECT>_created` and will include values for the name of the object and the namespace where it lives. The value is an epoch timestamp to the **millisecond**.

For example, the CronJob creation series is called `kube_cronjob_created`.

Comment: Hi, I tried kube_metrics with metrics kube_pod_start_info(the name not sure, something similar) before, it is giving epoch timestamp in seconds only. I will re check them once more

Comment: I tried with kube_pod_created, the value I received is 1551693420. On converting I got this value Monday, 4 March 2019 09:57:00. Milli second is not there I think

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure out how to get time in milli seconds?

Comment: I edited the codes in kubernetes source for kubelet and kube scheduler then deployed. It will show millisecond time stamp as per my requirement

Comment: @JibinNajeeb can you provided the source code, I'm interested in this?

Answer (score -2):

Start time of Pods can be fetched with various methods like:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=PodName--output jsonpath='{.items[*].status.conditions[?(@.type=="PodScheduled")].lastTransitionTime}'
```

Time will be in format like: `2022-06-23T08:28:23Z`

This can be converted in milliseconds with command:

```
date -d "2022-06-23T08:28:23Z" +"%s%N"
```

any other format of date can also be converted with above command like:

```
date -d "Thu, 23 Jun 2022 08:27:26 +0000" +"%s%N"
```

These commands will return output in milliseconds. Second date format can be fetched from describe pods of kubernetes with `cut`/`awk` commands.